# Socket.io event looping indefinitely when triggered once

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So I am trying to make a simple synced video player with NodeJS and socket.io, but when I trigger video on seeked event, it repeats and loops until connection is removed.
I am using the same version of socket.io on server and client side.

My client:

```js
<video id="avideo" src="" onseeked="onSeeked()" controls></video>

      <script>

      var socket = io({transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});
        
      function onSeeked() {
        var timestamp = document.getElementById("avideo").currentTime;
        socket.emit("seekdone", timestamp);
        console.log('client seeked')
      }
      
      socket.on('seekdone', function(timestamp) {
        console.log('server seeked')
        document.getElementById("avideo").currentTime = timestamp;
      }); 
      
      </script>
```

Server side:

```js
var io = socket(listener);

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  
  socket.on("seekdone", function(timestamp) {
    socket.broadcast.emit("seekdone", timestamp);
  });
  
});
```

The output I am getting in console after I seek on video:

```
client seeked
server seeked
client seeked
server seeked
client seeked
server seeked
client seeked
server seeked
client seeked
server seeked
client seeked
server seeked
client seeked
...
```

I have also tried making eventListener seeked but the outcome is same.
What I **think** is happening here is that I seek video, server sends me seek event to specified time and so it triggers itself once again.
when I change it to `socket.broadcast.emit` on server, the outcome is as well the same, but just when one user leaves, the looping stops.

Comment: setting `currentTime` fires the `seeked` event. That's where the loop begins.

Comment: @CallumMorrisson Yes because I want to make all other clients to seek to the time I have seeked, therefore making their currentTime same as mine when I seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your client-side js, if you change to:

```
      var socket = io({transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});
      var lastSeekFromServer = null; // NEW CODE
        
      function onSeeked() {
        var timestamp = document.getElementById("avideo").currentTime;
        if (timestamp !== lastSeekFromServer) { // NEW CODE
          socket.emit("seekdone", timestamp);
        } // NEW CODE
        console.log('client seeked')
      }
      
      socket.on('seekdone', function(timestamp) {
        console.log('server seeked')
        lastSeekFromServer = timestamp; // NEW CODE
        document.getElementById("avideo").currentTime = timestamp;
      });
```

this basically is making sure we don't tell `socket.io` about a `seeked` event that it triggered. There's likely a more elegant way to get the same effect, but this should hopefully get you thinking in the right direction.